# Enforce use of 2FA in .net core application using identity

Tags: security, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

I've set up 2 factor authentication in my .net core mvc application using the guide from [here](https://www.meziantou.net/implementing-two-factor-authentication-in-an-asp-net-core-application.htm)
This is all working fine however it relies on the user going into their account and setting up 2FA. Is there any way I can force the user to do this so all users must use 2FA?

Comment: This looks to be a pretty good solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/66666809/14608904

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One ways is during login  you check whether user have set the 2FA by :

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
var twoFactorEnabled = user.TwoFactorEnabled;
```

If it is false , you can then redirect user to config the 2FA page(`./Manage/TwoFactorAuthentication`) , after user set the 2FA and enable 2FA , `TwoFactorEnabled` in `AspNetUsers` table will be `True` and then during the login process , identity will automatically redirect user to `./LoginWith2fa` page for 2FA login if current user's `TwoFactorEnabled` value is true .

Comment: Problem with this implementation is that the user can simply navigate away via a url to avoid this, therefore making the 2FA not truly enforced.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late. But the way to do it is by making a custom Controller and overriding the OnActionExecuting method.

```
 public class CustomController : Controller
    {
        public readonly DataContext _db;
        public CustomController(DataContext context)
        {
            _db = context;
        }
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
             if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                
               var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
                UserModel user = _db.UserModel.Find(userId);
                if (user.TwoFactorEnabled==false && ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName != "TwoFactor")
                {

                   filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "TwoFactor" }));
                    return;

                }              
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```