# In ASP.NET Core Identity (standalone), how do you enforce 2FA?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, identity

I'm using ASP.NET Core Identity on a Razor Pages project.
If a specific policy is not met (e.g. 2FA is not enabled) for an authenticated user, how do you redirect to a specific page (e.g. Enable 2FA page)?

I'd like to avoid having to check against a claim in every OnGet, like:

```
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        var claimTwoFactorEnabled = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Type == "TwoFactorEnabled");

        if (claimTwoFactorEnabled != null && "true".Equals(claimTwoFactorEnabled.Value))
        {
            // You logged in with MFA, do the admin stuff
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect("/Identity/Account/Manage/TwoFactorAuthentication");
        }

        return Page();
    }
```

(as described in https://damienbod.com/2020/01/03/requiring-mfa-for-admin-pages-in-an-asp-net-core-identity-application/)

I did find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66666809/8684537) but it seems to require OpenIdConnect.  I'm using standalone Identity.

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa)? Usually the best place too look first.

Comment: There is one standalone Identity example there, which requires the code block above; I wanted to see if there's another solution that doesn't involve a check against the claim in every OnGet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started with `AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory` from https://damienbod.com/2020/01/03/requiring-mfa-for-admin-pages-in-an-asp-net-core-identity-application/:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
 
namespace IdentityStandaloneMfa
{
    public class AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>
    {
        public AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory( 
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, 
            IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor) 
            : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
        {
        }
 
        public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(IdentityUser user)
        {
            var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);
            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
 
            var claims = new List<Claim>();
 
            if (user.TwoFactorEnabled)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim("TwoFactorEnabled", "true"));
            }
            else
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim("TwoFactorEnabled", "false")); ;
            }
 
            identity.AddClaims(claims);
            return principal;
        }
    }
}
```

Plus, in ConfigureServices in Startup, added:

```
   services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("TwoFactorEnabled",
                    x => x.RequireClaim("TwoFactorEnabled", "true")
                );
                // you can also combine with a role based policy
                options.AddPolicy("RequireAdminRole",
                    policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin", "SuperAdmin").RequireClaim("TwoFactorEnabled", "true"));

            });
```

Then instead of adding the `if` logic to each `OnGet` method, I'm adding
`[Authorize(Policy = "TwoFactorEnabled")]` at the top of the code behind file, like:

```
    [Authorize(Policy = "TwoFactorEnabled")]
    public class DetailModel : PageModel
    {
```

Comment: The code in ConfigureServices should look for the claim you add to the user to indicate they are using MFA in AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory - which in your AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory code is the claim "TwoFactorEnabled" with a value of "true".

So the policy you add to authorization for MFA in ConfigureServices should be this:

`options.AddPolicy("TwoFactorEnabled", x => x.RequireClaim("TwoFactorEnabled", "true"));`

Comment: Thanks @PeterG !  Good catch.  I've updated the answer with your correction. 
(Clearly I was mixing up two different examples; one of which was working for me.)