# How to enforce 2FA in my .Net Core Identity Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity, multi-factor-authentication

I have a .net core MVC web app with Identity. The 2FA works fine. However the issue is  2FA isn't enforced. I can log in, get to the 'set up 2fa by scanning QR code' page, and then simply navigate to the root of my site in order to bypass setting up 2fa.

I've followed the best answer in [In ASP.NET Core Identity (standalone), how do you enforce 2FA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67980463/in-asp-net-core-identity-standalone-how-do-you-enforce-2fa)

(I've also tried following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa?view=aspnetcore-5.0#force-aspnet-core-openid-connect-client-to-require-mfa but one of the code snippets in there has a syntax error - https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPc4X.jpg)

But that has not worked. When I log in with 2fa, I get access denied. I even tried putting a break point in the method `CreateAsync` but it never seems to get hit.

Steps I have done:

Added class `AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory` to my project:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using PhotoUploaderForm.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IdentityStandaloneMfa
{
    public class AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
    {
        public AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
            IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
            : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
        {
        }

        public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);
            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;

            var claims = new List<Claim>();

            if (user.TwoFactorEnabled)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim("TwoFactorEnabled", "true"));
            }
            else
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim("TwoFactorEnabled", "false")); ;
            }

            identity.AddClaims(claims);
            return principal;
        }
    }
}
```

Added the below in `ConfigureServices`:

```
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        options.AddPolicy("TwoFactorEnabled",
            x => x.RequireClaim("amr", "mfa")));
```

To test this, on my home controller I have the following attribute `[Authorize(Policy = "TwoFactorEnabled")]`

Am I missing any other steps? I've been struggling with this for several days. Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this will fix all your issues with MFA but in ConfigureServices you are adding a policy for 'TwoFactorEnabled' which requires the user to have a claim of "amr" with a value of "mfa". However this claim doesn't appear to be added for the user in AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory. Instead you are setting a claim of "TwoFactorEnabled" with a value of "true".

If you update the code in ConfigureServices to this:

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    options.AddPolicy("TwoFactorEnabled",
        x => x.RequireClaim("TwoFactorEnabled", "true")));
```

In ConfigureServices you also need to add some code to inject your AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory. Adding this line to ConfigureServices should ensure that your AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory gets called when a user logs in:

```
services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

Comment: Hi, good spot. I amended my code to reflect this value of the claim. Unfortunately I am still getting a Access Denied on my home controller (due to the [Authorize(Policy = "TwoFactorEnabled")] attribute) even though my account has TwoFactorEnabled

I don't understand why the code in AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory is never being hit when i set a breakpoint. Do I have to call this class / its methods anywhere? Currently its just a class I added within my project. I'm not sure if my code is aware of it.

Comment: In ConfigureServices you need to add some code to inject your AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory. 

Adding this line to ConfigureServices should ensure that your AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory gets called when a user logs in:

`services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();`

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I added that code to inject that class and now it seems to be working. Much appreciated :-)

Answer (score -1):

After successful authentication of user, check if two factor authentication is enabled and then redirect user to page where OTP will be crosschecked, also you can add an option to send OTP again, please check this link for more help [link](https://www.webtrainingroom.com/aspnetcore/multi-factor-authentication), also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67980463/in-asp-net-core-identity-standalone-how-do-you-enforce-2fa)

Comment: You linked OP to a question they themselves based their question on..